# Wordpress container behind Apache2 host can't serve static files

Tags: wordpress, apache, docker

I have a Docker container with `wordpress:latest` in a host which has Apache 2.4 installed.

I added the lines below to my Apache configuration file, inside the `vhost` group:

```
ProxyPass http://localhost:8010
ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8010
```

When I try to access my URL I can reach wordpress homepage, however all static files point to localhost so my layout doesn't work.

What am I missing? Some setup at Apache? Wordpress itself?

Apache modules are already enabled.

**Edit 1:**
Forgot to mention: this piece of configuration is inside a `Location` directive, which is inside a `vhost` directive.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    <Location /usa>
        RequestHeader set X-Is-Reverse=Proxy true
        RequestHeader set X-Original-Host mysite.com.br
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8010
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8010
     </Location>
     ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the `Site URL` setting in wordpress matches the URL your clients are calling.
This is the documentation on how to change the site URL in wordpress:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Answer (score 0):

If you proxy pass to your backend like that, requests coming into your container will be sent with the `Host` header set to `localhost`. Apparently, the WordPress container takes care of the host that has been set in order to generate static assets links. Try setting the following proxy option:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

Just after the `ProxyPass` configuration line.
This options forward the `Host` HTTP header coming from the client over to the proxy connection. This way the backend will understand which public URL it's been called from and asset links should be correct.

Edit.

If you can't use the `ProxyPreserveHost` Directive you could try and directly set the `Host` header using:

```
RequestHeader set Host "your.host.name"
```

Comment: I beg your pardon. I forgot to mention that code is inside a `Location` directive. I'll update my question to reflect that.

Comment: That doesn't matter. My answer still applies

Comment: `ProxyPreserveHost` cannot be used inside `Location` directive. There's a syntax error when I try to reload Apache.

Comment: Uhm I wasn't aware of that, you're right. If you have only one proxy pass in your virtualhost you could set ProxyPreserveHost outside the Location I guess. What error are you having exactly?

Comment: `apachectl configtest`
`Syntax error on line 60 of .../sites-enabled/mysite.com.br:`
`ProxyPreserveHost not allowed here`
`Action 'configtest' failed.`
`The Apache error log may have more information.`

Comment: Added another option in my answer

Comment: Could it be a wordpress setting instead ? Is the site setting correct?

Comment: Can't say for sure. I looked in several config files but found nothing related to that. `functions.php`, `wp-config.php`, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Could you put this in a new answer? I'd like to make the right answer clearer for others.